# Brush following the cursor with lag in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I am using the brush in black color in photoshop CC but the brush follow the cursor with lag. It is not about performance issues, since if I move quickly the cursor the brush move quickly behind the cursor, but if I move it slowly, the cursor move slowly too, but always with some lag, if I draw a short line, as soon as I stop the cursor the brush start to go slowly.

I want it to work as previous version of Photoshop where the brush just follow withouth lag

I have a very good PC and have tryed to down the preferences of drawing and giving more RAM and virtual space in the disk but the same problem appear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using one of the newest Photoshops (2018..2020), it has Brush Smoothing ON by default. You can find the setting in the Tool menu on the top: values greater than zero will make brush follow the cursor with some delay to allow to smooth flickering and hand shaking. Here's the difference between drawing with smoothing and without:

[image]

Note that I also have `Show Brush Leash While Smoothing` option turned on that shows a little magenta line that represents the delay.

Comment: That was the problem, Thanks!